# Moving to SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy from TimeBasedRollingPolicy to rollover every mignight or a max size

Tags: logging, logback, rollingfileappender

When I use the following appender

```
<appender name="APPLICATION"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>D:/logs/log.txt</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%p %d [%t] %L - %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>D:/logs/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

I get the following warning:

> SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP is deprecated. Use SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy
>   instead

So I change the `SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP` to `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy`

which leaves me with this:

```
<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
```

but then I get:

> No TriggeringPolicy was set for the RollingFileAppender named
>   APPLICATION

Which makes me think that there is no such TriggeringPolicy so I revert the TriggeringPolicy back to `SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP` and change the rolling policy from `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` to `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy`.

My new rollingPolicy now becomes:

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>D:/logs/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
```

But then I get:

> TriggeringPolicy has not started. RollingFileAppender will not start

I am trying to achieve rollover every midnight or after a max size, whichever comes first. Now, I am using logback version: `1.2.3`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally figured out that `maxFileSize` had to be outside of `timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy` and `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` doesn't require this. So, the final logback.xml, which rolls based on time and size (whichever comes first) becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%p %d [%t] %L - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="APPLICATION" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>D:/logs/log.txt</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%p %d [%t] %L - %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>D:/logs/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>5GB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="javaportreader" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```